# Given a random sample size 40 from a binomial population, where p = 0.25 calculate the probability that the sample ratio is between 0.20 and 0.30.

Tags: probability

Given a random sample size 40 from a binomial population, where p = 0.25 calculate the probability that the sample ratio is between 0.20 and 0.30.

I don't have a clear idea of how solve this exercise:

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use the binomial distribution.  The specific answer is $\sum_{k=8}^{12}\binom{40}{k}.25^k.75^{40-k}$.   $k=8$ to $ 12$ comes from $.20,.30$ times $40$.